# Is there a way to implement SAML Shibboleth authentification in Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, saml, saml-2.0

I am currently working on a Flutter app for mobile (IOS and android) with firebase and I need to integrate SAML Shibboleth authentification.
After many research I found that the flutter package for saml has been deleted on pub.dev.

I've identified three potential solutions, but I'm unsure about their viability:

-Using Logto but this solution has monthly costs :
https://docs.logto.io/tutorial/how-to-build-saml-sign-in-with-flutter-and-logto/

-Another solution may be to implement SAML auth directly using HTTP requests ?

-Or using a web view in the flutter app however, i'm uncertain about the feasibility of this approach.

Or other solutions ?

I'm looking for a simple solution since I'm a junior dev.

If anyone has experience with similar situations or could provide guidance on the mentioned solutions, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 0):

Typically frontend applications is unsuitable for direct SAML communication as  as the application can not keep the a private key secret. Usage of private keys are essential to the workings of SAML.

I dont know how Logto work, but at a glance it looks like it uses a proprietary SDK that talks to their back end, which in term handels the SAML authentication. This is a common way to do it.

I would however suggest using a standard protocol between front end and back end like OIDC.

I would suggest either buying a service that does this or implement the back end service yourself.

On my blog I have a [writeup on how to do this using keycloak](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/post/saml-for-react-spa/). The write up is for ReactJs , but you could simply use flutter with a OIDC lib instead.